# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2016 remotely

Tags: sql-server, remote

I am trying to access SQL Server 2016 from outside of my network but each time I try I get this error message.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

The ports on my managed firewall are open, and I have also turned off Windows Firewall too in the event that this was the blocker but I am still getting the issue.

I have checked the Configuration Manager and its listening on port 1433, however, when I look at netstat -an I dont see this port is being listened on so suspect this may be where the issue exists.

A question I have is if configuration manager says its listening on this port, why is it not showing in netstat?

Also, what else can I try in order to gain access.

Thanks

Comment: What is the account you're using to connect?  A Windows account or a SQL Authentication account?

Comment: im am using the sa account, but its not even getting to authentication as far as I can see

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled under protocols, just checking?

Comment: @DenisT, yes it is

Comment: @CodeWarrior so if you run netstat -a -o, you don't see 1433 in the LISTENING state mapped to your SQL's PID?

Comment: This is what I am finding on the SQL Server PID at the moment TCP    0.0.0.0:49689          SPRPOGWEB001:0         LISTENING       9652

Comment: TCP    127.0.0.1:49724        SPRPOGWEB001:0         LISTENING       9652

Comment: TCP    192.168.1.182:49689    SPRPOGWEB001:51653     ESTABLISHED     9652

Comment: TCP    [::]:49689             SPRPOGWEB001:0         LISTENING       9652

Comment: @CodeWarrior from this, looks like, it's a named instance that is using the dynamic port 49689 to which this IP is connected -- 192.168.1.182:49689. Set of stupid questions... when you open Configuration Manager under SQL Server Network Configuration, how many Protocols for do you see? Do you have SSMS installed on the instance, if so can you connect using it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68013/discussion-between-code-warrior-and-denist).

Comment: @DenisT, after we worked on the system, it was down to the dynamic ports being set to 0 after we put IPALL at 1433 and this works now :)

Answer (score 1):

> should i construct the server name as tcp:ipaddress\instance, 1433

Absolutely no.

All that the network library needs to connect to SQL Server instance is it's `IP` + `port`.

When you are using `default instance`, `IP address` is sufficient as the default port is known, it's `1433`, so when you pass IP only, or PC name only, and your instance is listening on `1433` (even if it is named, but still configured to listen `1433`), the connection will succeed unless the port is unreachable due to firewall.

When `named instance` is used, you should pass it's `IP address` + `port` or `IP address` + `instance name`, but **not both `port` + `instance name`**.

In case you pass in `IP` + `port`, the network library just uses them.

In case tou pass `IP\instanceName`, `SQL Server Browser` should run. Is's `SQL Server Browser` that listens on `UDP 1434` (that should be open), takes `InstanceName` as the input and gives out instance's `port`.

When you pass in both `InstanceName` and a `port`, `InstanceName` is ignored. So not only it serves to nothing, it cheats you in that you may think there is an attempt to resolve `InstanceName` to the corresponding port, but it's no attempt at all: the `port` you are passing in is used.

In your particular case if 49689 port is used, all you need to connect to your instance is `192.168.1.182,49689` in SSMS + 49689 shoul be open.

If you are not sure what port is in use, just open SQL Server `error log` (you can do it using SSMS, notepad or any other text editor, or executing

`exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Server is listening on'`

`Configuration Manager` reflects the last configured value, but if the server was not restarted after configuring, the value for the port is not currently in use while `SQL Server error log` always gives you effective port values.

Comment: although this hasnt sorted my issue it has helped.

Comment: so you still cannot connect remotely? please show your actual connection string

Comment: I can connect now, but your answer although good didnt resolve my issue, plus i fixed it prior to seeing your response.

Comment: Why don't you descibe here what was your issue?

Comment: when i have time i will

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can access the SQL instance from the network with no problem. Check the edge managed firewall logs for port 1433 or the ports you are using for the SQL server. Also, check for any Deny policies on the managed firewall. Deny policies take precedence over Allow policies. It might be helpful to run a continuous ping from outside the network to the server by IP and also by name. if those are successful, try it by IP or name and port.